# Converting Big Clob into Table using XMLTable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, xquery, xmltable

I´m trying to convert a input clob variable from a store procedure into a xmltype and then, using XMLTable, trying to join it with other tables on my db, here is my code:

```
with clientes_data as (SELECT clientes.identificacion,clientes.tipoDoc,clientes.cuentas
                              from xmltable('/Clientes/Cliente'
                                passing xmltype(to_clob('<Clientes>
<Cliente><NumeroIdentificacion>94406495</NumeroIdentificacion><TipoIdentificacion>CC</TipoIdentificacion></Cliente>
<Cliente><NumeroIdentificacion>1136881480</NumeroIdentificacion><TipoIdentificacion>CC</TipoIdentificacion></Cliente>
</Clientes>'))
                                columns 
                                  identificacion varchar2(10) path 'NumeroIdentificacion',
                                  tipoDoc varchar2(2) path 'TipoIdentificacion',
                                  cuentas xmltype path 'Cuentas') clientes)
                             ,cuentas_Data as (
                                SELECT cl.identificacion,cl.tipoDoc,cuentasT.*
                                from clientes_data cl
                                LEFT JOIN
                                      xmltable('/Cuentas/Cuenta'
                                      passing cl.cuentas
                                        columns
                                          numCta varchar2(10) path 'Numero',
                                          tipoCta varchar2(3) path 'Tipo') cuentasT ON 1=1)
                      select * from cuentas_Data;
                      --select count(*) from cuentas_Data;
```

But I´m gettin this error:  **String literal too long...The string literal is longer tahn 4000 characters** when the input (the passing section) is longer than 4000 characters,so, I´m a little bit confused, cause it´s suposed that XMLTable have a parameter xmltype (kind of a clob size), but, I´m assuming that actually is a varchar2(4000)?

Thanks for any "light" on this.

Comment: I've seen this happen before.  Usually because some intermediate representation is getting treated as VARCHAR2 .  Take the sql and start removing parts so simplify until you don't get the error, then you can figure out which section is causing the problem

Comment: I did it, but still getting the same error :(